# Spark - process single file at a time from directory

Tags: apache-spark

Im in a situation with using Spark where I have a few hundred files that uncompressed are about a few gigs each, and I don't think I could fit that on a single machine, and having enough servers could be cost prohibitive. Im wondering if its possible to get Spark to instead of trying to load all the files and then process them, to load a single file, process it, and then move onto the next.

Comment: are all the files present in same directory? One way is to parameterize your application to process single file at time and while running the application , you can pass the file name that needs to be processed.

Comment: @RajatMishra They are all in the same S3 bucket, the issue though is that processing 300 files individually could be slower than processing them in a pre-defined batch size.

Comment: you can create a hive table having the entries for those and fine execute the process based on the entries. Even though you would running the process but it would be executing based on each entry.  I guess it would be slightly slower but but your problem will be solved.